# Why don't I see examples of back end components being loaded with a URLClassLoader?

Tags: java, web-applications, weblogic

We have some applications that are reaching out to a lot of our own internal web services. This causes performance issues and many single-points-of-failure for each app. We are brainstorming alternate strategies.

One thought was to dynamically load the classes with the back-end logic into the web apps, maybe with OSGI, but OSGI looks like it adds significant complexity.

Another thought was to just use a URLClassLoader to load the classes out of jars in the database into our web apps. I created a prototype and it's very simple code and seems to work beautifully. I looked around for examples, patterns, frameworks or anything that uses this technique and was not able to find any examples. This makes me think there's an issue with this technique that we're not seeing.

Are there issues with loading back-end classes to a web app in an application server (in our case, WebLogic) via URLClassLoader and delegating work to them? Or *is* there precendence and I just haven't found it?

**Update**

There were requests for the particulars of our current design...

There are web services that expose both a servlet (mapped to 'data/*') and a javascript file (served at 'uibuilder.js') which holds the js to build a "widget". The web app "consumers" have a generic servlet in them that proxies any "jsmodule/x/data/*" or "jsmodule/x/uibuilder.js" request back to web service x (where x is the module name). The web apps include `<script src="jsmodule/x/uibuilder.js"></script>` in their HTML which is proxied back the the web service and the js file is returned to the browser. Then js in the web app calls `jsmodule.x.buildUI(someDiv);` which causes the js to build a widget that the user interacts with. That widget then calls to the web app for back-end logic which are proxied back to the web service. This architecture allows us to share these "modules" (w/ a ui piece and cooresponding back-end) between web apps.

We're considering ways to eliminate the single-points-of-failure and performance hit from all these little web service calls. The js is easy. The proxy servlet in the web apps can just cache the js contents. The back-end calls to the servlet are harder. We're considering importing the back-end classes (currently in the web service) into the web app instead of making a web service call to invoke them (which in turn invoke other web services, etc).

Options:

- Bundle the Jars into the web apps (requires rebuild/deploy of all consuming apps if lib changes)
- Deploy a shared lib for each module into each app's server (this would end up being a LOT of shared libs)
- *potentially...* Using a URLClassLoader to load back-end classes from the db
- Web service (current design)

Clarifications...

The performance concern is to eliminate the call back to the web service for each request not the time it takes to actually load the classes.

Any options we go with will include version control, testing, etc.

**Update**

An example...

Let's say there's a PersonManager web service exposing 'personManager/addPerson'. Within the web service there's a PersonManager class with and addPerson(Person) method which loads the data into a db. 5 web apps call the service every time a person needs to be added (performance hit) and if the service goes down, all 5 apps are affected (single-point-of-failure).

The idea (which I'm still not sold on) is...

What if instead, the WS exposes a jar and the web app (instead of calling the web service for each request) loads the class once from the web service and delegates any addPerson requests to the class that is now loaded within the web app instead of calling the service. Now only the db has to be up. If the service goes down, no affect.

Comment: All ClassLoaders already load classes dynamically.  I guess it's possible that your network ClassLoader is faster than loading classes from disk… initially.  Once the classes are loaded, the difference is probably negligible.  Personally I'd rather have a self-contained deployable .war or .ear than an application which cannot run unless and until large binary objects are installed in a database—objects which I suspect are not version controlled.

Comment: Agree with @VGR - probably need more details about what/how you're calling classes to know what would work best.

Comment: How exactly does modifying a class loading strategy address either a single-point-of-failure concern or a performance concern over lots of little web service calls? Especially when you've already said it doesn't?

Comment: @EJP I added an example to my post, in an effort to clarify. In hindsight it would have been better to compare this idea to sharedlibs instead of the current web service design. W/ sharedlibs, you push libs to app servers. This idea is for the web apps to pull in the libs from a db with URLClassLoader.